# Are "parvus" and "magnus" the best adjectives to describe the length of a river?

Tags: vocabulary, adjective, word-choice, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In the first chapter of *Lingua Latina per se Ilustrata*, there are a series of sentences used to teach the usage of two adjectives, *magnus* and *parvus*.  For example:

> Nīlus fluvius magnus est.  Tiberis nōn est fluvius magnus, Tiberis fluvius parvus est. (22–23)
>
> Sicilia īnsula magna est.  Melita est īnsula parva. (29)

The context for these sentences is a map that clearly shows the relative *sizes* of islands, and the relative *lengths* of rivers.  Thus it seems that here *parvus* and *magnus* are being used to communicate both ideas.  But in English, a "big river" to me is one that is primarily wide or deep, not so much long.  Similarly a "small river" is usually easy to cross, but not necessarily short.

My question, then, is, do *parvus* and *magnus* strongly indicate the *length* of a river?  Are they suitable adjectives when clarity in this sense is needed? Or for the elimination of ambiguity is it necessary to use other adjectives, like *longus* and *brevis*?

My dictionaries don't help me much: Traupman begins his entry on *parvus* with "small, little, puny; short; young," but on the same word Cassell doesn't mention "short" except in relation to time.

Comment: Aren't short and narrow rivers (and conversely long and wide) usually correlated anyway?

Comment: @cmw There is correlation.  But if I'm looking at [this river](http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/560x560p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/154/32/78479955.jpg) in person, I'd call it a much smaller river than the one near my previous home, even though the pictured one is many times longer and in other places is wider (it's the Mississippi).  The picture just happens to be taken near the source of the river.

Comment: Put another way, here's what I'd call a [small river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_River#/media/File:Missrivermpls.jpg) and here's what I'd call a [large river](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mississippi_River#/media/File:Memphis_Bridge.jpg).  But it's the same river.

Comment: Ha, funny seeing a picture of my old city. I'm not sure the Romans---or we, even---would make that distinction. The Mississippi is a big river, even if it's narrow in certain places. They'd probably use [angustus](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23flum+~+%23angust).

Comment: I think you're right when we we know the full scope of the Mississippi's size/length.  But if you just look at those last two pictures, or if you stand on the bank at those two locations, without knowing anything more about the river, you'd be justified (I think) in saying "river B is bigger than river A."  On the other hand you wouldn't say "river B is longer than river A" because you wouldn't know – you could guess, but it'd be more speculative than a statement about size.

Answer (score 5):

The same adjectives can be used for a river as for a road or path. The usual words for 'broad' and 'narrow' are *latus* and *angustus*, and for 'long' and 'short' are *longus* and *brevis*. *Flumen magnum* and *flumen parvum* mean pretty much what they do in English, a 'big/great river' and a 'small/minor river'.

Various editions of the *Gradus ad Parnassum* (by Pyper, or Angel & Wintle, etc.) that were once used in teaching the composition of Latin verse (not to be confused with those for counterpoint in music ! ) are still available in print, giving lists of epithets for the several words for 'river', but as far as I can see they do not give any that are specifically for dimensions.

Comment: What is the difference between flumen and fluvius?

Comment: I think it's a matter of personal preference in use. Caesar never uses either _fluvius_ or _amnis_, but other authors including Cicero seem to choose whatever fits their current style. Maybe you should ask a separate question?

Comment: You could also do *rivulus* for a small river.

Comment: A little _rivus_, I presume?

Comment: And for a very little river: "O **fons** Bandusiae, splendidior vitro..."